# Msal interaction in progress error in at MsalService.acquireTokenRedirect if dont use MsalGuard

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-angular

i am not getting issue for below route.

```
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [
           MsalGuard
        ]
  }
```

I am getting issue for below route without `MsalGruad`. Need alternate for using `MsalGuard`

```
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
```

Comment: Please share the whole app.module.ts file so that I can determine your configurations in this file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.